# Use 'BR' instead of 'P' on hitting 'Enter' in 'FckEditor' for a particular instance only - not all instances in web application

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

I know, I can change the entry in the `fckeditor.js` as follows:

```
FckConfig.EnterMode = 'br';
```

But, this will change the setting for all the instances of editor shown on the web site, I just want it to change for a particular editor on a web page.

How can I change this setting at a Page level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about instead of changing that setting in the `fckeditor.js` file, you output that script on the pages you want it to occur on?

```
// After the FCKEditor JS has been referenced...
<script type="text/javascript">
    FckConfig.EnterMode = 'br';
</script>
```

Comment: FckConfig is undefined if I add it to the Page script.

Comment: How are you initiating the control on the page? You can directly target the instance of your editor to alter the config - see [here](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration_File) for details (method 2).